# SQL values to update pandas dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

i am doing a lot of sql to pandas and i have run in to the following challenge.

I have a dataframe, that looks like

```
UserID, AccountNo, AccountName
123,    12345,     'Some name'
...
```

What i would like to do is for each account number, i would like to add a column called total revenue which is gotten from a mysql database, som i am thinking of something like,

```
for accountno in df['AccountNo']:
    df1 = pd.read_sql(('select sum(VBRK_NETWR) as sum from sapdata2016.orders where VBAK_BSARK="ZEDI" and VBRK_KUNAG = %s;') % accountno, conn)
```

And i need to expand the the dataframe such that

```
UserID, AccountNo, AccountName, TotalRevenue
123,    12345,     'Some name', df1
...
```

The code that i have so far (and is not working casts a **getitem** error)

```
sets3 = []
i=0
for accountno in df5['kna1_kunnr']:
    df1 = pd.read_sql(('select sum(VBRK_NETWR) as sum from sapdata2016.orders where VBAK_BSARK="ZEDI" and VBRK_KUNAG = %s;') % accountno, conn)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([(df5['userid'][i], df5['kna1_kunnr'][i], accountno, df5['kna1_name1'][i], df1['sum'][0])], columns=['User ID', 'AccountNo', 'tjeck', 'AccountName', 'Revenue'])
    sets3.append(df2)
    i += 1

df6 = pd.concat(sets3)
```

This idea/code is not pretty, and i wonder if there is a better/nicer way to do it, any ideas?

Comment: The data comes from a lot of different databases and tables, it is very much cut and paste procedures i am doing.

Comment: then i think you should read all of your tables into individual dataframes, join them together on appropriate keys, and then do your summarization. Show us 5 - 10 rows from a representative selection of your tables

Comment: @PaulH - or the reverse, write all data to DB and run queries in MySQL

Comment: @parfait Of course. But this question seems more focused on the pandas-end of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider exporting pandas data to MySQL as a temp table then run an SQL query that joins your pandas data and an aggregate query for *TotalRevenue*. Then, read resultset into pandas dataframe. This approach avoids any looping.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
...

# SQL ALCHEMY CONNECTION (PREFERRED OVER RAW CONNECTION)
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pwd@localhost/database')
# engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@hostname:port/database") # load pymysql

df1.to_sql("mypandastemptable", con=engine, if_exists='replace')

sql = """SELECT t.UserID, t.AccountNo, t.AccountName, agg.TotalRevenue
         FROM mypandastemptable t
         LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT VBRK_KUNAG as AccountNo
                    SUM(VBRK_NETWR) as TotalRevenue
             FROM sapdata2016.orders 
             WHERE VBAK_BSARK='ZEDI'
             GROUP BY VBRK_KUNAG) agg
         ON t.AccountNo = agg.AccountNo) 
"""

newdf = pd.read_sql(sql, con=engine)
```

Of course the converse is true as well, merging on two pandas dataframes of existing dataframe and the grouped aggregate query resultset:

```
sql = """SELECT VBRK_KUNAG as AccountNo
                SUM(VBRK_NETWR) as TotalRevenue
         FROM sapdata2016.orders 
         WHERE VBAK_BSARK='ZEDI'
         GROUP BY VBRK_KUNAG 
"""

df2 = pd.read_sql(sql, con=engine)

newdf = df1.merge(df2, on='AccountNo', how='left')
```

Comment: The latter seems like the thing i was looking for! Thanks a lot - quick follow up, i have been using the raw connection because i could not get sqlalchemy to work. But i hope with this example i will get i to :-)

Comment: Got it. And do note the commented out slqalchemy connection that interfaces with `pymysql` module.